# sparse matrix implementation for user,item pairs

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a dataset of millions of records consisting of 100,000 users who bought a subset of 20,000 items, in the form:

```
<user1, item1>
<user1, item12>
...
<user100,000, item>
```

I need to keep track of a matrix of size (items x users) = (20,000 x 100,000) with a 1 if the user has bought the item and zero otherwise. Currently I am using a traditional numpy array, but it takes too long to process this in later steps. Can anyone recommend an efficient way of using one of SciPy's sparse matrices, which will still allow for searching the matrix based on indexing?

Comment: It's easy to make a sparse natrix fron dense one, and easy switch between fornats.  Experiment,

Comment: what would be the goal of this? in my case: i need to create this sparse matrix once and then read it later to check where the 1s are stored. If i first create it as a dense matrix and then transform it to sparse, I would have to transform it back to dense when I want to read out the 1s right?

Comment: You can get the 1s from the sparse matrix using `nonzero()`, which gives a tuple of the indices.
Considering this, would the said approach work for your use-case ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your updated answer is very useful. I think this can work for my case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution building a dense pivot table with 0s and 1s, and then creating the equivalent sparse matrix. I chose [`lil_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix), but other options exist.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

ar = np.array([['user1', 'product1'], ['user2', 'product2'], ['user3', 'product3'], ['user3', 'product1']])

rows, r_pos = np.unique(ar[:,0], return_inverse=True)
cols, c_pos = np.unique(ar[:,1], return_inverse=True)

pivot_table = np.zeros((len(rows), len(cols)))
pivot_table[r_pos, c_pos] = 1

print(pivot_table)

# Convert the dense pivot table to a sparse matrix
s = sparse.lil_matrix(pivot_table)

# I can access the non-nul indices using nonzero
print(s.nonzero())
```

This gives :

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]]
(array([0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 0, 2], dtype=int32))
```

---

*Appendix*

Should it be relevant, here is another solution not using scipy, but [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) :

```
In [34]: import pandas as pd

In [35]: df = pd.DataFrame([['user1', 'product1'], ['user2', 'product2'], ['user3', 'product3'], ['user3', 'product1']], columns = ['user', 'product'])

In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
    user   product
0  user1  product1
1  user2  product2
2  user3  product3
3  user3  product1

In [37]: df.groupby(['user', 'product']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[37]: 
product  product1  product2  product3
user                                 
user1           1         0         0
user2           0         1         0
user3           1         0         1
```

Also, please not that this would count the number of product bought by each customer (which might be interesting, depending on your use-case and dataset).

You will still be able to search your data using this library.

Comment: I actually already tried using pandas, but compared to numpy's 2-D array it was a factor 30-40 slower. The problem isn't creating a matrix of zeros and ones, but to efficiently store and read these elements by index. Therefor the sparse package from the SciPy package seems perfect, but lacks clear examples for cases like these (note that the matrix contains much more zero's than ones).

Comment: @Keyb0ardwarri0r i edited my answer to add a sparse-based pivot table

Comment: Aren't `r_pos` and `c_pos` the same thing as the `s.nonzero()` arrays (with a possible reordering)?  Also look at `np.nonzero(pivot_table)`.

Comment: You can make a sparse matrix directly  with `s = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(r_pos.shape,int), (r_pos, c_pos)))`.  `s.nonzero()` (essentially) returns the `row` and `col` attributes of a `coo` matrix.